# Drawable draws the picture smaller than I want

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am using in my application two `ImageView` (s) imageView1 is fullScreen and `imageView2` is smaller, when I draw Drawable in `imageView1` it draws with the specific dimension, but when I try to draw the same picture in `imageView2`, iy is drawn smaller, even if I specify bigger dimensions:

```
drawable = Resource.getDrawable(R.drawable.find_position);
drawable.setBounds(1,1,70,70 ); 
drawable.draw(myCanvas2);
```

I put my picture in `hdpi` folder

Comment: if imageView2 is smaller it is rather obvious that it will draw smaller Drawables

Comment: but it is enough large to contain my picture

Comment: @pskink, you right, because when I cgange my imageView2 to be bigger it draws the picture as I want, but before also imageView is enough large to contain it???

Comment: "iy is drawn smaller", smaller than what? smaller than the imageView1? smaller than original Drawable in pixel size?

Comment: @pskink, smaller than imageView1, even that I try to draw it with the same dimentions (drawable.setBounds(1,1,70,70 ); )

Comment: use scaleType = "matrix"

Comment: @pskink, Thank you, you right Mr pskink, I want to submit your answer, please can you write it bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to avoid auto scaling use scaleType = "matrix"